# Is there any way to capture ajax post request URL in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

In my project i have one ***"Update Report"*** button. If i will click on that button it will send one post request via ajax to **ReportManagmentDAO.java**, it will render report and shows on ui.

But, i want to capture that post url in Selenium for testing purpose.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.
Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve